# Source Code Different When Using CefSharp Function GetSourceAsync() than when Calling ViewSource()

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I have the latest version of CefSharp installed and when I call ViewSource(), it opens up a notepad window with the source code. But when I call GetSourceAsync() the code is very different and missing the HTML I need in the **var html** that is shown in the Notepad window. The only work around would be to somehow copy the contents of the code in Notepad into my app and use it. Does anyone know how to get the html as shown in the NotePad window? I'm running the application in the Windows 7 Pro operating system using Visual Studio 2017 Express. Here is my code...

```
        private void WebBrowserFrameLoadEndedAsync(object sender, FrameLoadEndEventArgs e)
        {
                chromeBrowser.ViewSource();

                chromeBrowser.GetSourceAsync().ContinueWith(taskHtml =>
                {
                    var html = taskHtml.Result;
                });
            }
        }

Here is the web page that the browser goes to...

chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://www.amazon.com/product-reviews/B084RCFDJ3/ref=acr_search_hist_5?ie=UTF8&filterByStar=five_star&reviewerType=all_reviews#reviews-filter-bar");
```

Comment: GetSourceAsync gets a snapshot in time of the source, you just need to wait a little longer, this is common for dynamically content.

Comment: That's not true. I waited until the ViewSource() method displayed the code in a NotePad window, then called

                chromeBrowser.GetSourceAsync().ContinueWith(taskHtml =>
                {
                    var html = taskHtml.Result;
                });

The html var still did not show the same code as in the NotePad window

Comment: Is there a way to Override the ViewSource() method so I can get the html code but not open a Notepad window? Or is the chromeBrowser.GetSourceAsync().ContinueWith(taskHtml => { var html = taskHtml.Result; }); wrong code?

Comment: You cannot override ViewSource. Just because you called ViewSource first doesn't actually mean that it completes first, it immediately returns, opening notepad when the  GetSource call is made to the render process. Both methods internally call GetSource chromium command, the difference is when the string is read as it's a shared memory section. This gives a distinct but subtle difference in behaviour. https://github.com/chromiumembedded/cef/blob/7702d96b3329c59394e89227955dae33d8aae037/libcef/browser/frame_host_impl.cc#L122

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, I was searching the source for the wrong phrase. So now I just call the following...

```
string source = await chromeBrowser.GetBrowser().MainFrame.GetSourceAsync();
```

Comment: This is equivalent to the code you had previously. GetSourceAsync is just an extension method for getting the main frame source.

Answer (score 0):

I've gone into detail on the difference between GetSource and ViewSource further down.

Some important things to note about `FrameLoadEnd`.

- Is called for **every frame**, if your page has multiple frames then it will be called multiple times
- It's called when the initial resources have finished loading, if your website is dynamically created/rendered then your call maybe happening too early.

```cs
//FrameLoadEnd is called for every frame, if your page has multiple frames then it will be called multiple times.
private async void BrowserFrameLoadEnd(object sender, FrameLoadEndEventArgs e)
{
    var frame = e.Frame;

    var source = await frame.GetSourceAsync();
}

//To only get the main frame source
private async void BrowserFrameLoadEnd(object sender, FrameLoadEndEventArgs e)
{
    var frame = e.Frame;

    if (frame.IsMain)
    {
        var source = await frame.GetSourceAsync();
    }
}

// If your website dynamically generates content then you might need to wait a
// little longer for it to render. Introduce a fixed wait period, this can be
// problematic for a number of reasons. 
private async void BrowserFrameLoadEnd(object sender, FrameLoadEndEventArgs e)
{
    var frame = e.Frame;

    if (frame.IsMain)
    {
        //  Wait a little bit of time for the page to load
        await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(500);
        var source = await frame.GetSourceAsync();
    }
}
```

---

Explanation of the difference in behaviour

Firstly `ViewSource()` returns immediately, `Notepad` is being launched **after** the `GetSourceAsync` call has completed.

Both methods send a `GetSource` message to the render process which returns a `ReadOnlySharedMemoryRegion`. When you read the data from the shared memory section ends up with a different snapshot in time.

```cpp
void CefFrameHostImpl::ViewSource() {
  SendCommandWithResponse(
      "GetSource",
      base::BindOnce(&ViewTextCallback, CefRefPtr<CefFrameHostImpl>(this)));
}

void CefFrameHostImpl::GetSource(CefRefPtr<CefStringVisitor> visitor) {
  SendCommandWithResponse("GetSource",
                          base::BindOnce(&StringVisitCallback, visitor));
}
```

[CEF Source](https://github.com/chromiumembedded/cef/blob/7702d96b3329c59394e89227955dae33d8aae037/libcef/browser/frame_host_impl.cc#L122) reference.

The `CefFrameHostImpl::GetSource` method which `GetSourceAsync` calls completes very quickly as it simply creates a string from the shared memory section.

The `CefFrameHostImpl::ViewSource` method whilst returns immediately is much slower and takes additional processing to create a file on disk, write that string, spawn notepad.

HTML Source is always a snapshot of source for a given point in time. For static web pages, time makes no difference, for dynamically rendered/updated websites a few hundred milliseconds can mean you get entirely different source.
When the shared `ReadOnlySharedMemoryRegion` is converted into a string means there is a subtle difference in the source you end up getting.

Comment: Version `102` will add a basic `WaitForSelectorAsync` implementation which is useful for detecting when a given DOM node is present. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/pull/4095 For WPF/OffScreen implementations I'm adding a new `WaitForRenderIdleAsync` method which an be used to wait for the page to stop updating https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/pull/4080 (it's not possible to implement `WaitForRenderIdleAsync` for WinForms yet)